# QAF | Getting scenario tags in TestNg listener

Tags: testng, listener, qaf

I would like to get the Scenario tag details in TestNg listener to help in writing custom reports using TestcaseId & IntId for each scenario.

```
 @priority:1 @TestcaseId:VFF-265 @IntId:615d440932e941018806cfc5  @sit-1 
 Scenario : Testing login is successfull
```

The present workaround I have implemented is to add details in scenario name and use result.getTestName() in TestNg listener and split the details from scenario name. Only issue with this implementaiton is internal ID and TC id is visible and making the testcase names long:

```
 @priority:1 @TestcaseId:VFF-265 @IntId:615d440932e941018806cfc5  @sit-1 
 Scenario : [VFF-265]_[615d440932e941018806cfc5]_Testing login is successfull
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using qaf with TestNG runner, it will use `TestNGScenario` as `ITestNGMethod` implementation. `TestNGScenario` is extended `TestNGMethod` which has addition method `getMetaData()` which will give you meta data of the test case.  Any method from testng returning `ITestNGMethod` or `TestNGMethod` will return `TestNGScenario` object.
Below is example

```
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
    TestNGScenario scenario = (TestNGScenario) tr.getMethod();
    Map<String, Object> metadata = scenario.getMetaData()
}
```

If you are working on custom reporting, best way is to implement [TestCaseResultUpdator](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/integration_with_other_tools.html). You can refer qaf inbuilt [reporters](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/tree/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/report) and [qaf-support-elasticsearch](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-elasticsearch#usage).

Answer (score 0):

result.getTestName() returns string. So you can use java methods to pick the last sentence after last underscore. you may use substring or split methods from java.

Examples:
// Java program to demonstrate working of split()
public class GFG {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str = "GeeksforGeeks:A Computer Science Portal";
    String[] arrOfStr = str.split(":");
    for (String a : arrOfStr)
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

}
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/

Comment: The answer you have mentioned is already implemented in my code, problem I'm looking to solve here is getting the details of the scenario Tag, not from Scenario name. I have mentioned the scenario name solution in question to tell, I have already implemented a workaround. Thanks for taking the time in answering.